# Visual Studio Code Wont Run Subsequent Scenarios

Tags: scenarios

I'm having difficulty getting Visual Studio Code to run any scenarios subsequent the primary scenario. I have no idea why it won't do so. I feel I've followed all instructions and could use a hand in solving this issue. Problems always propel us forward, no? :)

I used the Gherkin Style to build my first Scenario. Using the command prompt, I ran the automation, and it performed as expected. Afterward, I built the second Scenario, again using the Gherkin Format, and ran the automation.
The program ran the first automation, then quit back to the input screen of Visual Studio.
After several attempts at running the second scenario, I built a third Scenario and tried running that, to no avail.

Also, I saved my progress after building each scenario.